# Panel Heading not displaying correctly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am new-ish to twitter bootstrap, and am trying to have a panel, within a panel.

The first outer panel is fine, but my inner one - the header seems to cut off the edges. Here's a screenshot of what's happening:

[image: Strange Headers]

And here's the code I attempted to use:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4>@String.Format("{0} {1} - {2}", Model.Institution, Model.Description, Model.AccountType)</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <br />
        <div class="col-md-4 panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3>Account Details</h3>
            </div>

            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="">
                        <small>
                            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Institution)</small>
                        <br />@Model.Institution<br />
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Can you see why I am losing the edges?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to wrap your Panel with `.col-md-4` and place it inside a `.row`

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">


    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            Panel content
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>
</div>
```